# Bash script to extract information from a block of text spanning multiple lines

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I am trying to extract track information from `MKV` files using `mkvinfo` from a `bash` script. The output is a long series of lines with repeating patterns as delimiters for various track properties of various track types. An example of a track is:

```
…
| + A track
|  + Track number: 6 (track ID for mkvmerge & mkvextract: 5)
|  + Track UID: 11555278830806058806
|  + Track type: subtitles
|  + (Unknown element: TrickTrackFlag; ID: 0xc6 size: 3)
|  + Enabled: 1
|  + Default flag: 0
|  + Forced flag: 0
|  + Lacing flag: 0
|  + MinCache: 0
|  + Timecode scale: 1
|  + Name: Spanish
|  + Language: spa
|  + Codec ID: S_TEXT/UTF8
|  + (Unknown element: TrackAttachmentLink; ID: 0x7446 size: 11)
|  + Codec decode all: 1
| + A track
|  + Track number: 7 (track ID for mkvmerge & mkvextract: 6)
…
```

There can be multiple instances of a given track type and the number of lines for a track is somewhat variable. I need to extract certain track properties from specific track types. For example, if I want to find all instances of the `subtitles` track type and extract the `Track number` and the `Codec ID`, I can pipe the results through grep:

```
mkvinfo "file.mkv" | grep "subtitles" -B 2 | grep "Track number"
```

This outputs the lines containing the track numbers for all subtitle tracks. I have to put the lines into an array and filter them to get the first number so I can use it with `mkvpropedit`, which requires the first number.

Similarly:

```
mkvinfo "file.mkv" | grep "subtitles" -A 10 | grep "Codec ID: " | sed 's/^.**: //'
```

outputs the codec IDs for all subtitle tracks.

This works fine **IF** I know exactly how many lines there are before/after the line containing `subtitles`. The problem is, the exact number of lines to include varies from file to file. So what I need to do is to output the entire block of lines between `| + A track` and a line beginning with `|+` OR  `| +` OR `EOF`. I also need to filter the block to extract the first `Track number` and the `Codec ID`. I tried using `| grep -Eo [0-9]+ | head -1` to extract the first number of each track but it only works on the first track found and quits. If there's a way to make it work for all tracks in one line that would be helpful. The second example I gave using `sed` works for the `Codec ID`.

The bottom line **QUESTION** is:

> How can I extract **specific properties** of **specific track types**, such as the example given, and put them into an array or arrays for further processing?

I am hoping to be able to meet the following criteria:

1. I want to use existing `bash` (GNU bash, version 4.3.30(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0)) utilities like `sed`, `awk`, `grep`, …
2. I don't want to have to create an 'intermediate file'
3. I want to simply **pipe** the output of `mkvinfo` into the various utilities

I found lots of threads that show how to use `sed` to find a block of text between two **words** but I could not get the code to work with **entire lines** or **strings containing spaces**. Maybe there is a way to do that but I don't know enough about `sed` to be able to adapt the code to my situation.

**Please explain in detail *how your code works* so I can 'learn how to fish' so next time I can do it myself.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When processing multiple lines in complex ways, my tool of choice is `awk`.

In each matching pattern, we save the match in a variable.
Finally, when we encounter the string indicating a new block (`| + A track`), or we reach the end of the stream, we print the value of the variables we are interested in (track number, codec id), but only if the type is subtitles.

```
mkvinfo ... | gawk '
    match($0, /Track number: ([0-9]+)/, m) {TN=m[1]}
    match($0, /Codec ID: (.*)$/, m)        {CI=m[1]}
    /Track type: subtitles/                {SUB=1}
    /^\| \+ A track$/ {if(SUB) print TN, CI; unset SUB}
    END               {if(SUB) print TN, CI; unset SUB}'
```

You need `gawk` to have the match function to capture parenthesized groups.

Comment: That works superbly. Thanks a lot! Now I have to study the code to understand how it works, for future reference. I definitely will use `awk`|`gawk` in the future.

Comment: This is just a bit less common that the classical awk oneliner you can find around, where you have `awk '/pattern/ {print $something}'`, but the functioning is exactly the same. We need match due to the irregular nature of the input (different separators across lines)

Comment: I notice that the first two `match` statements return the entire match in `m[0]` and just the regex after the space in `m[1]`. How would you put both track numbers into the array? Would that require a separate `match`? Also what does the ending `/^\| \+ A track$/` statement do? Does it insure that the previous matches came after an `| + A track` line? How does that work?

Comment: really, `match($0, /pattern/) {...}` is equivalent to `/pattern/ {...}`

Comment: the pattern `/^\| \+ A track$/` matches the beginning of a new block (track). if you have seen a track before (you known that because SUB is 1), you print the interesting variables. then you unset SUB.

Comment: I am confused about the order of the matches. The output of `mkvinfo` is `A track`, `Track number`, `Track type`, `Codec ID` but the order of the matches is different with the `A track` one being last. How do all these matches get tied to the same record?

Comment: each line is checked among all patterns. in this particular case, since your information spans multiple lines, the order in which patterns are specified is not relevant. but there are some cases in which the order of patterns can make a difference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76390/discussion-between-hmj6jmh-and-mescalinum).