# parse the output of mkvinfo in bash with gawk

Tags: bash, awk, gawk

I'm using the code described on this thread to parse mkvinfo output

[Bash script to extract information from a block of text spanning multiple lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29881826/bash-script-to-extract-information-from-a-block-of-text-spanning-multiple-lines)

my data:

```
+ Pistes du segment
| + Une piste
|  + Numéro de piste : 1 (identifiant de piste pour mkvmerge & mkvextract : 0)
|  + UID de piste : 2143402115
|  + Type de piste : video
|  + Marque de laçage : 0
|  + Identifiant du codec : V_MPEG4/ISO/AVC
|  + Données de codec privées, longueur 50 (profil h.264 : High @L3.1)
|  + Durée par défaut : 41.708 ms (23.976 images/champs par seconde pour une piste vidéo)
|  + Marque par défaut : 1
|  + Cache minimum : 1
|  + Piste vidéo
|   + Largeur (pixels) : 1280
|   + Hauteur (pixels) : 530
|   + Largeur à l'écran : 1278
|   + Hauteur à l'écran : 530
| + Une piste
|  + Numéro de piste : 2 (identifiant de piste pour mkvmerge & mkvextract : 1)
|  + UID de piste : 1488372266
|  + Type de piste : audio
|  + Marque de laçage : 0
|  + Identifiant du codec : A_AAC
|  + Données de codec privées, longueur 2
|  + Langue : fre
|  + Marque par défaut : 1
|  + Audio track
|   + Fréquence d'échantillonnage : 48000
|   + Canaux : 2
| + Une piste
|  + Numéro de piste : 3 (identifiant de piste pour mkvmerge & mkvextract : 2)
|  + UID de piste : 1313701432
|  + Type de piste : audio
|  + Marque de laçage : 0
|  + Identifiant du codec : A_AAC
|  + Données de codec privées, longueur 2
|  + Langue : eng
|  + Marque par défaut : 0
|  + Audio track
|   + Fréquence d'échantillonnage : 48000
|   + Canaux : 2
| + Une piste
|  + Numéro de piste : 4 (identifiant de piste pour mkvmerge & mkvextract : 3)
|  + UID de piste : 1052586390
|  + Type de piste : subtitles
|  + Marque de laçage : 0
|  + Identifiant du codec : S_HDMV/PGS
|  + Langue : fre
|  + Marque par défaut : 0
| + Une piste
|  + Numéro de piste : 5 (identifiant de piste pour mkvmerge & mkvextract : 4)
|  + UID de piste : 392408513
|  + Type de piste : subtitles
|  + Marque de laçage : 0
|  + Identifiant du codec : S_HDMV/PGS
|  + Langue : fre
|  + Marque par défaut : 0
| + Une piste
|  + Numéro de piste : 6 (identifiant de piste pour mkvmerge & mkvextract : 5)
|  + UID de piste : 1184974912
|  + Type de piste : subtitles
|  + Marque de laçage : 0
|  + Identifiant du codec : S_HDMV/PGS
|  + Langue : eng
|  + Marque par défaut : 0
| + Une piste
|  + Numéro de piste : 7 (identifiant de piste pour mkvmerge & mkvextract : 6)
|  + UID de piste : 2028534438
|  + Type de piste : subtitles
|  + Marque de laçage : 0
|  + Identifiant du codec : S_HDMV/PGS
|  + Langue : eng
|  + Marque par défaut : 0
| + Une piste
|  + Numéro de piste : 8 (identifiant de piste pour mkvmerge & mkvextract : 7)
|  + UID de piste : 1986046695
|  + Type de piste : subtitles
|  + Marque de laçage : 0
|  + Identifiant du codec : S_HDMV/PGS
|  + Langue : eng
|  + Marque par défaut : 0
|+ Cluster
```

I want to store in var the language of subtitles available and in another var the audio language available.

This code work fine for subtitles:

```
mkvinfo "$tmdb_file" | gawk '
match($0, /Numéro de piste : ([0-9]+)/, m) {TN=m[1]}
match($0, /Langue : ([a-z]+)/, m)        {CI=m[1]}
/Type de piste : subtitles/                {SUB=1}
/^\| \+ Une piste$/ {if(SUB) print TN, CI; unset SUB}
END               {if(SUB) print TN, CI; unset SUB}'
```

But this code for audio return also subtitles track

```
mkvinfo "$tmdb_file" | gawk '
match($0, /Numéro de piste : ([0-9]+)/, m) {TN=m[1]}
match($0, /Langue : ([a-z]+)/, m)        {CI=m[1]}
/Type de piste : audio/                {SUB=1}
/^\| \+ Une piste$/ {if(SUB) print TN, CI; unset SUB}
END               {if(SUB) print TN, CI; unset SUB}'
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are seeing is because of the

> `unset SUB`

line used in the body of the `awk` command. It is *NOT* a `awk` built-in, but a shell built-in to reset the variable value.

[The unset builtin command](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/unset)

> The unset builtin command is used to unset values and attributes of shell variables and functions. Without any option, unset tries to unset a variable first, then a function.

So for your `Awk` just reset the variable with initializing it to zero as `SUB=0`,

```
mkvinfo "$tmdb_file" | gawk '
   match($0, /Numéro de piste : ([0-9]+)/, m) {TN=m[1]} \
   match($0, /Langue : ([a-z]+)/, m)          {CI=m[1]} \
   /Type de piste : audio/                     {SUB=1} \
   /^\| \+ Une piste$/ {if(SUB) print TN, CI; SUB=0;} \
   END {if(SUB) print TN, CI; SUB=0}'
```

which produces output as

```
2 fre
3 eng
```

Comment: Many thanks for your detailed answer, it works perfectly now. regards.